# Android - How to change UI from another thread in signed mode

Tags: android

I needed to change the UI from another thread, so I used the following code:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        status_txt.setText("Some msg ...");
    }
});
```

And `TextView status_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);`

In debugging mode, when I tested the app in my phone using USB Debugging everything was OK and UI changed correctly. But, when I exported and signed the app as an APK file, after installation the UI won't change.

What is wrong?

---

**UPDATE** my whole codes are:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Map;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;


@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
public class Httpd extends Activity
{
    TextView textIpaddr;

    private WebServer server;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        server = new WebServer();
        try {
            server.start();
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            Log.w("Httpd", "The server could not start.");
        }
        Log.w("Httpd", "Web server initialized.");
    }


    // DON'T FORGET to stop the server
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (server != null)
            server.stop();
    }

    public void setTextHistory(String input) {
        textIpaddr.setText(input);
    }

    private class WebServer extends NanoHTTPD {

        public WebServer()
        {
            super(8080);
        }

        @Override
        public Response serve(String uri, Method method, 
                Map<String, String> header,
                Map<String, String> parameters,
                Map<String, String> files) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    setTextHistory("Some Text ...");
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I recommend to you put the `Log` inside this method. Can you give a full code when you use this function?

Comment: @IllegalArgument and deathember - I my added whole codes.

Comment: what the superclass of `NanoHTTPD`?

Comment: @deathember - https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fi/iki/elonen/NanoHTTPD.java

Comment: debuge your built with `signed in apk` and see the log, because your code looks fine.

Comment: @maddy - I set the `debuggable=true` in Manifest and did what you said. Now everything is OK and UI changes !!!

Comment: @maddy - Thanks but what was wrong without `debuggable=true` ???

Comment: have you tried without `debuggable`  because the "debuggable=true" is just for `Whether or not the application can be debugged, even when running on a device in user mode`.

Comment: @maddy - without `debuggable` the UI won't change and it is a sort of strange !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update your ADT boundle and the error will go away.
http://developer.android.com/sdk